# MySql - Create a view with longtext cast into VARCHAR(255)

Tags: mysql

I am willing to create a view on a table with a longtext column. But I would like that in my view this column be varchar(255). And Yes I would like to cut the "extra" text.

When I do a substr in the create script the data type is still longtext

Anyone could help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about casting the longtext as a varchar?

```
 CREATE VIEW foo AS
 SELECT ID, CAST(MyLongText as char(255)) AS MyVarchar
 FROM Table
```

Comment: This is not a syntax that MySql known. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Samuel: oops, should be `char`. Corrected in the answer.